# Is there any non-UI SOAP-UI client for Linux, or something similar?

Tags: xorg, java, https, solaris

I wish to run SOAP-UI on a linux (solaris) machine with very limited functionality, where we don't even have a UI, and so I cannot install any software on it or open X11 forwarding.

I can however run java applications, and could settle for any alternative to SOAP-UI.

The objective is to be able to send a SOAP message as-is to a URL.

I have struggled with writing my own java client for this, however I'm facing issues with SSL authentication, and so I need to use a client that is guaranteed to behave as expected.

The error i'm getting when sending the SOAP message in my java application is the below, however note that for the same URL, I can call a GET and get the WSDL (using the Apache HTTP Client):

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <172.30.40.50> != <host056.boomgroup.local>
```

Comment: Solaris is not Linux, but a rather different Unix OS.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so Solaris is way off-topic here... However, on http://unix.stackexchange.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Comment: The solution is related to the application, not the OS, so it's not a problem, I posted a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a guide for this [here](http://blog.kasunbg.org/2013/04/run-soapui-command-line-terminal-linux.html), which does load tests.

For normal functional tests, the official documentation is [here](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html).

A sample command for functional tests goes like:

> sh /opt/app/home/SOAP-UI/SoapUI-5.0.0/bin/testrunner.sh -a -s"Test_Suite2" -r -f/opt/app/home/SOAP-UI/test-project/reports/ /opt/app/home/SOAP-UI/test-project/test-soapui-project.xml